# Validate date column in CSV with Data Factory

Tags: csv, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I'm attempting to use Data Factory to import a CSV file from Azure File storage into SQL Azure. So far I'm using the copy data task to read the CSV and save into SQL Azure.

My CSV file contains 2 date columns with the date in the format dd/MM/yyyy. How can I set Data Factory to validate and read dates in this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow my step, I tried this and Data Factory can validate and read dates in "dd/MM/yyyy" format.

This is my csv file, also has two columns with the date in the format "dd/MM/yyyy".
[image]

The difference between us is I import my file  from Azure blob storage into my Azure SQL database by using Copy Data.

If you want Data Factory can validate and read dates in "dd/MM/yyyy" format, during File format settings, you must set the the schema,  specify the column type and the format. Please see this picture:
[image]

After copy active completed,  the date with "dd/MM/yyyy" format will be parsed to the default format "yyyy-MM-dd".

[image]

Hope this helps.